Symfony3.4から4.4のバージョンアップがうまくいきません。
Symfony3.4で稼働しているプロジェクトSymfony4.4にバージョンアップを行なっています。
以下のサイトを参考に作業しています。
公式サイト：
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/UPGRADE-4.0.md
https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/flex.html
https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony4-upgrade/framework-config
Symfony Flexを導入し、ディレクトリの変更を行いました。
また、ライブラリのアップデートも行いました。
現在は3.4のapp/config/config.ymlなどから、設定内容をconfig/package/***.yamlに移植しています。
doctrineの移植をしたところで以下のエラーにつまづきました。
エラー内容
> post-install-cmd: @auto-scripts
> auto-scripts: Symfony\Flex\Flex->executeAutoScripts
Executing script cache:clear
Executed script cache:clear  [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
!!  
!!   // Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug                       
!!   // true                                                                        
!!  
!!  
!!  In Container.php line 248:
!!                                                                                 
!!    Circular reference detected for service "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manage  
!!    r", path: "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager -> doctrine.orm.default_enti  
!!    ty_manager".                                                                 
!!                                                                                 
!!  
!!  cache:clear [--no-warmup] [--no-optional-warmers] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>
!!  

doctrine.yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: master
        connections:
            master:
                driver:   'pdo_mysql'
                host:     '%database_host%'
                port:     '%database_port%'
                dbname:   '%database_name%'
                user:     '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset:  UTF8
                default_table_options:
                    charset: UTF8
                    collate: utf8_unicode_ci
                options:  '%database_default_options%'
            importer:
                driver:   'pdo_mysql'
                host:     '%database_host%'
                port:     '%database_port%'
                dbname:   '%database_name%'
                user:     '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset:  UTF8
                default_table_options:
                    charset: UTF8
                    collate: utf8_unicode_ci
                options:  '%database_importer_options%'

    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: master
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                auto_mapping: ture
                mappings:
                    ArgamaModelBundle:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Arman/ArmanModelBundle/Entity'  
                        prefix: 'Arman\ArmanModelBundle\Entity' 
                        alias: doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager

            importer:
                connection: importer
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                mappings:
                    ArmanModelBundle:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Arman/ArmanModelBundle/Entity'
                        prefix: 'arman\ArmanModelBundle\Entity'
                        alias: doctrine.orm.importer_entity_manager

エラー内容は循環参照エラーでしたが、原因がよくわかりませんでした。
どこを見るべきか、解決方法等ありましたら、よろしくお願いします。
補足：デバックを行なっていると奇妙な現象を見つけました。Kernel.phpにてバンドルの読み込み処理でなんでもない文字列をデバックで出力すると２回出力されました。エラーは２回目の出力後に現れます。
これは、循環参照と関わりがあると思います。
